# SSRS count with switch

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to do a count based on what two fields in the data are

```
=switch((Fields!color.value = "Higher" and not isnothing(Fields!ncdrqtrpercent.Value)),count(iif(Fields!ncdrqtrpercent.Value >= Fields!percentile.Value,1,nothing)),(Fields!color.value = "Lower" and not isnothing(Fields!ncdrqtrpercent.Value)),count(iif(Fields!ncdrqtrpercent.Value <= Fields!percentile.Value,1,nothing)))
```

the first part works when it is higher but the count does not work when its the opposite with it being lower

im not sure if this is the correct way to do this expression or if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You have an aggregate COUNT inside the SWITCH. If there's any grouping, it would only check the first record for the COLOR and PERCENT and then aggregate the rest.

I think this is what you want:

```
=SUM(
    SWITCH  (
            Fields!color.value = "Higher" AND NOT ISNOTHING(Fields!ncdrqtrpercent.Value) AND Fields!ncdrqtrpercent.Value >= Fields!percentile.Value, 1, 
            Fields!color.value = "Lower"  AND NOT ISNOTHING(Fields!ncdrqtrpercent.Value) AND Fields!ncdrqtrpercent.Value <= Fields!percentile.Value, 1, 
            1 = 1, 0
            )
```

I prefer to use SUM with 0/1 instead of count in cases like this - though I suppose the 1/Nothing works the same.

This evaluate each record and return a 1 if it meets the criteria in either of the first two SWITCH criteria. The `1 = 1` is to assign the records that don't meet the criteria a 0 for the SUM.